# i want addition of while loop float values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a problem to addition of float values in PHP
i have try many times but i don't know how to do that.
below my code.

```
$selctAllAmount = "SELECT * FROM amount WHERE id = '$id'";


if($resultAmount = mysqli_query($conn, $selctAllAmount)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultAmount) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAmount)) {
            $AmountAll = $row['amount'];
            $counts = count($AmountAll);
            echo $counts;
        }
    }
}
```

$AmountAll variable have both float values like 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3
how can i count all these values like 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.3 = 2.3
please help me someone thanks StackOverFlow

Comment: should use `SUM(amount) as total_amount` instead of `*`, then just fetch that one row, then dont need the loop

Comment: Nothing in this question has anything to do with JavaScript or html as it is tagged. Only use tags that are directly relevant to the problem

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the result and add it to a variable `$total` for each iteration.

Also, be sure to use prepared statements when using variable inputs in your queries.

```
$selctAllAmount = "SELECT amount FROM amount WHERE id = ?";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($selctAllAmount)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($amount);

    $total = 0;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $total += $amount;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    echo $total;
}
```

Even better, run a single query using `SUM()`,

```
$selctAllAmount = "SELECT SUM(amount) as amount FROM amount WHERE id = ?";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($selctAllAmount)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($amount);
    $stmt->fetch();

    echo $amount;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in this way

```
 $AmountAll += $row['amount'];
```

OR

if you want to do the SUM in SQL query use SUM, for example

```
SELECT SUM(amount) As total FROM tablename
```

Comment: how can i subtract the $AmountAll like if i have 2.3 then subtract it $AmountAll - 2

Comment: $AmountAll -= $row['amount'];

Comment: how can i subtract $AmountAll with 1 or 2 whatever number and send send to database float values from subtracted values

Comment: $AmountAll = $AmountAll - 1

Comment: sir if i have 4.4 rupees selected from all rows to donate and i iam donating 1 rupess so i have subtracted amount 3.4 rupess then how can i update all rows with money between 3.4 like 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4 please help me first divide 3.4 with loop and then update with rows